# Javascript Logic to find greater number to match input

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

Actually I was working on a logic where I got an array and an input var, I need to compare that var with the array and find the smallest number in that array without using sorting,
for eg. I got an array something like

```
const arr = [20,25,13,10,3,5,9,22];
```

and an input like

```
var inputt =3;
```

So I need to find the smallest number in array but greater then the input in the above situation the expected answer is " 5 ".

What should be the approach, I have tried performing a loop around the array and find the smallest number but cant figure out how to get the smallest number from an array which is greater then the input given.

```
var myarr = [5,3,9,10,7];
var smallest = arr[0];

for(var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(myarr[i] < smallest){
        smallest = myarr[i];   
    }
}

console.log(smallest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [20,25,13,10,3,5,9,22];
const input = 3;
const res = Math.min(...arr.filter(num => num > input));

console.log(res)
```

Filter out numbers that are less than the input, then find the min of those.

Comment: Keep in mind that this gives "Infinity" if there aren't any numbers in the array or if none pass the predicate.

Comment: how to get out from that infinity? any solution?

Comment: Infinity is an appropriate return, @MarkStone.  What's the minimum of an empty set of numbers?  How you handle that is application specific.

Comment: I have used if else there and its working cool. just like if(res != 'Infinity')

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Let me know if it works

```
var myarr = [5,3,9,10,7];
var smallest = arr[0];

for(var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(myarr[i] < smallest){
        if( myarr[i] > inputt){
             smallest = myarr[i];  
        }
    }
}

console.log(smallest);
```

Comment: Not working gets the smallest number which ever comes first not check the full array

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduce, this returns undefined if no matching number.

```
const res = arr.reduce((acc, v) => v > input && (acc === undefined || v < acc) ? v : acc, undefined);
```